# Charging 4s 18650 with one iMax B6

Tags: battery-charging

I see the following statement in my iMax B6 manual:

```
It isn't necessary to connect an external balancer for balance charging.
```

Do I understand right that this entails that I can charge a serial-connected pack of 18650 elements with just one iMax B6 device and without disassembling them? If I do, do anybody can confirm that I understand the schematics right?

[image: iMax B6 18650 charging]

Comment: If your schematic is accurate, then yes.  The charger has a balancer built-in, behind the Balance port, and it may even form part of the charging logic.

Comment: I am confused. Does your battery pack have a balance plug that you can connect into the balance port of the charger as you show in your schematic? If you plug the balance plug into the balance port, I would think it will balance charge your pack. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm going to assemble a 18650 pack by myself. What I want to know is how to make a balance plug that I can connect to iMax.

Comment: I think it is right. But the manual is not super-clear. It may be that the highest and lowest cells need to be connected both to the balance charger port and the main charge port.

Answer (score 4):

I assembled a battery pack myself.

Your schematic is not correct, because the chargers expect a balancing connector with n+1 contacts: negative plus positive of each element. Basically the 5 wires from your battery pack are ALL needed for the balance.

In addition, you have to connect to the charger also the (two additional) leads you use for the normal use.

See the image (Lipo or LiIon, doesn't matter).

[image]

Comment: This is correct, a 4S pack uses a 5 pin balance connector.

Comment: Hi, what is the AMP that you set on the Imax bt6 in order to charge safetly? I have a 2S 18650 Sony VT6 pack